# header, container and footer need to contain whole layout without using fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any way to make the header, container and footer need to contain whole layout without using fixed position in CSS
html [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2y3vp1f/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <img src="https://www.ecobin.com.au/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/footer_grass.jpg" alt="">  
   </header>
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer>footer come here</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header img {
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: #666;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: actually there is header, footer and container, I don't want to use fixed position, as you know we can fix the whole layout by using `fixed` position in CSS  but is there any other way by which the header will remain in top and container in middle and footer in bottom without scrollable. Hope these helps

Comment: are you looking for an alternative for `position: fixed` ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#page {
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
#content {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks good , but I can't give height to header as becasue the image is reposnsive. so in low resolution the image looks bad, So is there any way without adding height to header

Answer (score 0):

Your current structure forces the page to work like you want it to. header, content area and the footer. Their positioning will not change unless you force it to.

If you are planning to have this content within a specified area of page, just put the whole content in a div tag and give the width in percentage. Later use "margin: 0px auto;" on that div which will align it in center.

I hope that's what you're looking for. Please let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the flex model for this (unless you want to support old browsers)

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/k2y3vp1f/3/)

```css
/*layout */

body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.container {
  flex: 1;/*flex child to fill whole space left and eventually scrolls */
  overflow: auto;
}
/* makeup*/

.container {
  background: pink;
}
img[src*="grass"] {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
footer {
  background: #86B31C
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header><!-- any height -->
    <img src="https://www.ecobin.com.au/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/footer_grass.jpg" alt="" />
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer>footer content of any height
    <br/>come here</footer>
</div>
```

**note** Mind to set some min-height on wrapper or max-height on footer+header to avoid, them to fill the whole window's height on small screens,  and avoid container to be squeezed down to zero ;)